# How to get the action value of Html form in Android programming

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

How to get the action url value of Html form in Android programming using `AccessibilityService`? I implemented a `AccessibilityService` class and also I can get all fields using below code;

```
ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> fields = new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();

private void getFields(AccessibilityNodeInfo source) //~ getRootInActiveWindow()
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo node = source.getChild(i);

        if (node == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (node.getChildCount() == 0)
        {
            if (node.getClassName() != null && node.getClassName().toString()
                .contentEquals("android.widget.EditText")) // 'EditText' is for example
            {
                // Add it to list...
                fields.add(node);

                Log.d(TAG, node.getClassName().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, node.getViewIdResourceName());
            }
        }
        else //~ node.getChildCount() > 0
        {
            getFields(node);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how I can recognize which node is a Html form, and How to get the action url value of it...